# Query fetching case-sensitive results in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field like this in my indexed documents
 "screen_name : "9GAG"

And this is my query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "screen_name": "9gag"
    }
  }
}
```

Im getting zero hits. But when I replace  "9gag" with "9GAG" it works fine. Why is this happening and how can this be fixed?

Comment: Can you share the mapping of your `screen_name` field (i.e. analyzed or not analyzed)? Have you tried to use a `match` query instead of `term`?

Comment: This might help you: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/analysis-intro.html